# How can I repeat an image on the x-axis for x number of times?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code that dynamically adds an image each time I enter a number in the input box. I want the number of the images equal to the number that the user enters.

My code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById('number1').value;

  for (var t=4; (t<=a); t++){
    var str =  document.getElementById("x");
    str.innerHTML += "<div><img src='images/light.png>'</div>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1"  oninput="myFunction()" value="3" > 
<div><img src="images/n.png" id="x"></div>
```

When I have run the code, no errors were displayed, but also the code did not work. Just the image of the id "x" appears.

Comment: Possibly because you are missing a closing `>` in your `innerHTML`.

Comment: also, `innerHTML` should be called to manipulate an element which has both opening and closing tags, such as `<div>..</div>`. Image elements do not have closing tags.

Comment: I added it,it did not work gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following changes

- Consider using a `change` listener
- Consider creating elements through `createElement` API
- Put the id on the element that will contain the images, not the image itself
- Another change beyond this is to consider using [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) but it might be overkill for this example

```js
const input = document.getElementById("number");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function changeHandler(e) {
  const newValue = e.target.value;

  container.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < newValue; i++) {
    const el = document.createElement("img");
    el.src = "images/light.png";
    container.appendChild(el);
  }
}

input.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" value="3">
<div id="container"><img src="images/n.png" id="x"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I want to keep adding the images only on the x-axis on the same line without going down if the entered number is a big number. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You've made two mistakes. Here are the corrections:

- add the missing ">" in the end of the innerHTML injection
- move id="x" from the img tag to its container div tag.

  <div id="x"> <img src="images/n.png"> </div>

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  
  
  var str =  document.getElementById("x");
  str.innerHTML = '';
  
  for (var t=4; (t<=a); t++){
    str.innerHTML += "<img src='images/light.png'>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1"  oninput="myFunction()" value="3" > 
<div id="x"><img src="images/n.png"></div>
```

Comment: @Graficode The code breaks when number selected is less than 3

Comment: The OP's code has many issues. But the scope of the question is why the images are not showing up, so only that part of the plumbing was addressed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#number1');
var imgBlock = document.querySelector('.img-block');
    
input.addEventListener('input', function () { 
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;
  
  imgBlock.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < input.value; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR30Eaz1gUbe9_uGKhZK30xVncS-TPBqURWE4P2Noh0BGAdd9R4Qg';
    img.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    imgBlock.appendChild(img);
  }

  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
  imgs.forEach(item => {
    item.style.width = width / imgs.length + 'px';
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1"> 
 <div class="img-block"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR30Eaz1gUbe9_uGKhZK30xVncS-TPBqURWE4P2Noh0BGAdd9R4Qg" id="x"></div>
```

Comment: number of images changes size of images